# Pass static variables as props React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Do i can pass `static variables` as props down to children?

***Example code***

```
class ExampleClass extends Component {
  static MyStaticVariable = "I need to pass this as prop";

  render() {
    return (
     <Component/> 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
<Component yourProp={ExampleClass.MyStaticVariable} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to pass static variable?

Your Child class can access Parent static variables directly.

```
ExampleClass.MyStaticVariable
```